# Allow only non-assignable variable as function parameter

Tags: c#, performance, cil

I have two functions, `Source()` and `Sink()`.
`Source()` is creating new objects, `Sink()` is acquiring them.
As soon as `Sink()` is called, no other (accidental) use of the object should be possible.

Currently, I am achieving this, via ref parameters:

```
var data = Source();
// ...
Sink(ref data);
// data is set to null, so nobody will use it afterwards
Assert.IsNull(data); // data is null now
```

In principle, this works fine,
accidental usages of `data` after the call to `Sink` are immediately detected.

Sometimes, I find situations, where I would like to avoid the temporary variable.
But this is not allowed:

```
Sink(ref Source()); // compile error: CS1510 A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable
```

Is there a possibility, to change the signature of `Sink()` / `Source()`,
so that I have the opposite behavior, i.e., temporaries are allowed, but named variables are not?

```
// This is, what I would like to have
var data = Source();
Sink(data); // compile error, named variable not allowed
Sink(Source()) // ok, temporary object
```

---

The motivation for this question, is a class `Chunk`, that serves as a read only wrapper for `byte[]`-arrays. By default, a new `Chunk` copies over all bytes from the array (so nobody can modify an existing `Chunk` through some backdoor).
But for efficiency, I can also transfer ownership:

```
Chunk c = Chunk.Acquire(ref someByteArray);
```

The problem are now functions of the form `byte[] ComputeChecksum(...)` where I cannot write

```
Chunk c = Chunk.Acquire(ref ComputeChecksum(...)); // not allowed
```

and either need a helper variable (cluttering the code), or create additional copies.

I know ways to work around the problem, but I am curious, if there is a built-in solution in the compiler (similar to the `std::move()`-semantics in `C++`).

Comment: You could always use a custom code analyser that marks such usage as an error. It's always possible to bypass it on _purpose_, but it covers the accidental usage quite nicely.

Comment: Maybe write a `Sink` method that takes a lambda in the form of `() => Source()` and encapsulates the individual calls that use `ref`. (And maybe another lambda for the intervening "..." code ?)

Comment: If `Source` really takes no parameters (and it's not a simplification for the purpose of the post), you could pass the method group, so it would just be `Sink(Source);`

Comment: I don't think your idea of limiting this to method calls would work. What if I do `Sink(ThisDoesNotCreateNewObject())`, where `ThisDoesNotCreateNewObject` returns an object stored in a static property of some class somewhere, which means that I can still access it after `Sink` returns. You'd have to limit `Sink` to accepting method calls that create new objects.

Comment: Side note: is there any reason to use `Chunk` over `Span<byte[]>`

Comment: @Sweeper: As I said, changing the signature of `Source`  would be an option as well, i.e., requiring some special signature on `Source`, that I then would not add to `ThisDoesNotCreateNewObject`. (more or less the opposite of `ref return`-values

Comment: @Charlieface: Legacy... `Chunk` was introduced 2009, `Span` about 2018. Within the `Chunk`-class, `ReadOnlySpan<>` is now used quite extensively.